# Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7fbf30520550>

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, python-multiprocessing

I'm using TensorFlow training a deep learning model and the model is successfully trained however at the end it returns this error message to me:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7fbf30520550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in __del__
    self._change_notifier.put(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in put
    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

This looks like a pool destructor error to me, but I'm not sure how to fix it, any idea why it would happen?

Comment: This issue occurs usually when multiple threads are open for multi processing and could not close before the program ends. Please check the similar issue resolved here in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50487) link for the work around.

Comment: TL;DR: The workaround mentioned by @user11530462 is in [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50487#issuecomment-997304668)